# Which one is suitable datastructure for file comparison?

Tags: data-structures

Two files, each of size in terabytes. A file comparison tool compares i-th line of file1 with 
i-th line of file2. if they are same it prints. which datastructure is suitable.

1. B-tree
2. Linked list
3. Hash tables
4. None of them

Comment: I don't get it. Where does the data structure come in?

Comment: a,b,c,d - Multiple choice on his mid-term :)

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: I broke it now :) Have no idea to get abcd 'numbering' for a list :(

Comment: @ Michael Dorgon :  this is not a mid-term question. Its a written test question asked in amazon interview

Comment: Are the comparisons always between lines with the same number?  I.e., is it the 1st line of `file1` and the 1st line of `file2`, the 2nd with the 2nd, etc.?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock : yes comparison are always between lines with the same number

Comment: @Mariselvam: Given that, will you ever need to store multiple lines from the same file at the same time?

Comment: @ Jeremiah Willcock : yes we can store multiple lines at the same time ( obviously we cant store terabytes of lines ) to reduce the number of file reads . If we not storing multiple lines at the same time, probably no data structure is neede i guess.

Comment: @Mariselvam: Does multiple-line buffering require any of the data structures listed in the question?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using Longest Commons Subsequence, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm) out...

Answer (score 0):

Depends how much memory you have and how fast it needs to go - though this really feels like an exam question rather than a true question.  I'd go as far as to say that any of the above answers could be 'correct' depending on what exactly the machine specs were.

Comment: this is not an exam question , Its an amazon interview written test question

Comment: Then you should not be asking it here.  To do so is to deceive Amazon for the answer is from Stack Overflow, not from you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd need to make sure that both lists are sorted (this could be done using a [merge sort](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~prabakar/cop4722/Common/SortingIllustration.pdf)).  Then you compare the two files, line by line.

Comment: How will sorting help? actually sorting will just make things out of order... can u explain a bit more.